# Find character in a number which is in String format

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I find a string in a number?

A simple example is follows

```
private char check() {
        String sample ="1212kkk";//121hhh444 | 12-22
        return 'k';//'h' | '-'

    }
```

If anything other than number I want to return that value.

How can I get the first character from this ring?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String result = sample.replaceAll("\\d" ,"");
return result;
```

Comment: return result.charAt(0); // first character

Comment: the more effective way should be to loop n chk char by char n return 1st non-digit char ...

Answer (score 1):

```
private char check() {
    String sample ="1212kkk";//121hhh444 | 12-22
    return sample.replaceAll("[0-9]+", "").charAt(0);

}
```

Comment: If you add the + quantifier after the [0-9] character class your pattern will be more efficient.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why it is faster?

Comment: @smttsp: for 123ABC, with [0-9] you find 1 replace it, you find 2 replace it,... with [0-9]+ you find all consecutive digits and have only one replace

Comment: Hi if i have a String like +123ddf or *1212FFF i can validate the string using following regex but failed to find the letter in the string using the same regex `(^[+?]([0-9])+$)||(^([0-9])+$)||(^[*?]([0-9])+$)` please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the signature of your method, otherwise the caller would not be able to tell when the string is "good" (i.e. contains only digits). One way would be returning [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), a wrapper around the `char` primitive.

Inside, you can use a simple regex `[^0-9]` to match the first non-digit in a `String`. When there is no match, return `null`. This way the callers would be able to call your method like this:

```
private static Character check(String s) {
    Pattern firstNonDigit = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]");
    Matcher m = firstNonDigit.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group().charAt(0); // The group will always be 1 char
    }
    return null; // Only digits or no characters at all
}
...
Character wrongChar = check("12-34");
if (wrongChar != null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I something getting wrong? If you save something as an int(number) you can't have a string value in there. If you, however mean, that you have a string, and in its string numbers, and want to get only the numbers, this regex command will get all number digits

```
/(\d+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

try with guava

[CharMatcher.indexIn](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#indexIn%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

something like: 
`if(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.indexIn(yourString) != -1) return yourString.charAt(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.indexIn(yourString));`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yourString = "123abc";
    int indexOfLetter = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.indexIn(yourString);
    if (indexOfLetter != -1) {
        char charAt = yourString.charAt(indexOfLetter);
        System.out.println(charAt);
    }
}
```

prints `a`

Answer (score 0):

\D is a non-digit, and so then \D* is any number of non-digits in a row. So your whole string should match \D*.

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\D*").matcher(sample);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.err.println(m.group());
    }
```

Try with `\\D*` and `\D*` please.